# Import 2 wx windows from each other

Tags: wxpython

Imagine that we have 1.py and 2.py as a main window and a sub window, and we want to create a button to navigate between them.
For an explanation of the idea see the code:
1.py (the main window):

```
import wx

class app(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(app,self).__init__(parent,-1, title= 'example app')
        p = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.Center()
        self.btn = wx.Button(p,-1, 'go')
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBtn)
        self.Show()

    def onBtn(self, event):
        # I need the code to import the 2.py's class.

app = wx.App()
school(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

2.py (the sub window):

```
import wx

class appTwo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(appTwo,self).__init__(parent,-1, title= 'example app')
        p = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.Center()
        self.btn = wx.Button(p,-1, 'back')
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBtn)
        self.Show()

    def onBtn(self, event):
        # I need the code to import the 1.py's class.

app = wx.App()
app2(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Why have you two separate wx loops, shouldn't it all be in in loop?

Comment: You are setting yourself up for a circular import and you have not made clear, what it is that you attempting to achieve with this example. Whatever it is you are trying to achieve, there will be a better way than this. As a side note, neither of those 2 code snippets will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example I have defined two panels (not Frames) and you can switch between them. The button events are handled in the Frame and not in the individual panels

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Wx App'

        self.panel_one = MainPanel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def onBtn_one(self, event):
        self._clear_sizer()
        self.panel_two = SecondPanel(self)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two)

    def onBtn_two(self, event):
        self._clear_sizer()
        self.panel_one = MainPanel(self)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one)

    def _clear_sizer(self):
        for child in self.sizer.GetChildren():
            if child.IsSizer():
                if child.IsSizer():
                    self._clear_sizer(child.GetSizer())
            else:
                child.GetWindow().Destroy()
        self.sizer.Clear()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        txt_info = wx.StaticText(self, label='panel 1')
        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'go to 2')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onBtn_one)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txt_info)
        sizer.Add(btn)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)


class SecondPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        txt_info = wx.StaticText(self, label='panel 2')
        btn = wx.Button(self,-1, 'go to 1')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onBtn_two)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txt_info)
        sizer.Add(btn)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```